# How can I comment in a Jinja directive?

Tags: jinja2

I have a Jinja `set` directive as follows:

```
{% set mylist = [
  "item 1",
  "another item",
  "yet another item",
] %}
```

**I would like to add a comment to the second list item. Does Jinja support that?** I've tried the following:

```
{% set mylist = [
  "item 1",
  "another item",  # My comment
  "yet another item",
] %}
```

and

```
{% set mylist = [
  "item 1",
  "another item",  ## My comment
  "yet another item",
] %}
```

, but none of them work. I'm using Jinja 2.6.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since you are using Jinja 2.2+ then you can use whatever your environment configures for [`line_comment_prefix`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#jinja2.Environment) (part of the [line statements](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#line-statements) feature).  This feature must be enabled by the application that Jinja is embedded in (for example, in Flask, this is done by setting `app.jinja_options['line_comment_prefix'] = "whatever#you$want"`).

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

app.jinja_options['line_statement_prefix'] = '#'
app.jinja_options['line_comment_prefix'] = '#::'
```

Then you can write a template that uses line comments:

```
{% set mylist = [
  "first item",
  "another item", #:: needed for raisins - see #12345
  "a third item"
] %}
```

If you are using Jinja 2.1 or lower then those versions do not support inline comments.  However, you can use a comment block:

```
{#
BUG: Added "another item" because of raisins.
Don't remove it until #12345 is fixed
#}
{% set mylist = [
  "item 1",
  "another item",
  "yet another item",
] %}
```

Comment: Is this still true four years later, or are inline comments now possible somehow?

Comment: I used jinja2 directly in python 3.6 and set `line_comment_prefix='#::'` in the Environment but rendering a template gives a `TemplateSyntaxError` `Unexpected char '#'` when trying to use a comment in a `{% set ` directive.

Comment: This seems wrong - at least as of version 3.1.  Seemingly, line comments are only allowed within blocks, but not within Jinja expressions. Your example above produces `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '#'` for me.

Answer (score 4):

I guess everyone's going to find that out via documentation but just in case, I'll leave it here as well:

> Since Jinja 2.2, line-based comments are available as well. For
> example, if the line-comment prefix is configured to be ##, everything
> from ## to the end of the line is ignored (excluding the newline
> sign):
>
> ```
> # for item in seq:
>     <li>{{ item }}</li>     ## this comment is ignored
> # endfor
> ```